# How to handle OAuth access tokens

Tags: javascript, oauth

I have been exploring a couple of OAuth API's lately and bumped into an API that requires my page's code to handle and access token. I used the following in the HTML for example:

```
<script>
var client = thisapi.createClient({
  accessToken: '0b7f6x59a0'
})
</script>
```

I am able to make calls to the API and retrieve the kind of data I need as long as I can access this token on my page. But it is exposed to the public. So how can I hide this kind of information?